# Unable to edit page numbers in Adobe Acrobat Pro print window

Tags: printing, numbers, edit, acrobat, page-numbering

I'm encountering an issue in Adobe Acrobat Pro where I cannot edit the page numbers in the print window. I can select the page number text, but I am unable to make any changes to it, whether by typing or pasting. I've tried various methods without success. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following method, but it did not work. I have googled it but could not find any relevant search.
[image]